Android - Circle in google map goes behind tiles on zoom
I have been trying adding circle over google map using following code
 mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                            .center(userLocation)
                            .radius(100)
                            .strokeWidth(2f)
                            .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#2681C76F"))
                            .strokeColor(Color.parseColor("#7f70be")));

it is working fine and adding circle over map.
But when i zoomed the map, somehow newly loaded tiles overlap the cirlce as shown in image.
Please let me know if i need to changed map style ? or redraw circle on every zoom
Using implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
This is before zoom

This is after zoom

